# Get time above from current time from MySQL current day

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hope all are fine. I have a question. I have a table in MySQL with the names of times.

The table contains two main fields `from_time`, `to_time`, and I can enter more times. I want something like a user enters current date, PHP checks current time and gets me the times above from the current time

For example:

I have 3 times rows

| id | from_time | to_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10:00 am | 11:00 am |
| 2 | 2:00 pm | 4:00 pm |
| 3 | 8:00 am | 9:00 am |

**current_date = 24-6-2022**

So the current time is of my country is 9:56 AM.

**So the results I should get are row 1 and row 2**

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTimeTable` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Please provide data structure and values as table or image instead of raw data. To convert date you need to use strtotime and operate with int.

Comment: I do not understand your query.  "9:56 AM" is part of NONE of those ranges.  Why would anything be picked?

Comment: @TimRoberts: "get me the times **above** from the current time."

Comment: "above" meaning "later in the day than"?  "Above" is not the usual way to put this.  In that case, the `to_time` is irrelevant.  Just something like `SELECT * WHERE from_time > '09:56';`.

Comment: "above" mean
current time is 10:21 am of my country
i want the rows that are after from this time like 11am 12am 1pm 2pm 3pm 4pm etc

Comment: @TimRoberts yes i want something like that.

Comment: OK, then do that.  Without knowing your table definitions, we can't give you exact SQL.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks Man You have just made my day.
i am getting exact results. thank you very much for your precious time you are great.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to store time in unixtimestamp using that you can easily check grater than less then value refers to GMT
if you don't know what is unix timestamp then check (https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: Absolutely the wrong answer.  MySQL has native date/time support.